# How to overcome audio player issues in html5 - javascript applications?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, autoplay, audio-player, javascript-audio-api

I have experienced audio player issues with the combination
 of HTML5-JS applications. Specifically in mobile browsers.

Auto play audio without user interactions is not working for me and make me to raise this question. Since I'm not familiar with web apps, I just want to know about the issue in detail.

Also I need clarification about the above scenario that either falls under the category of issues/bugs or comes under regulations/limitations in the platform.

If I have answer for the above question then I can decide that whether I can find solution or not to break the regulations.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not the issue, but security policy of mobile browsers

Comment: @MysterX Thank you for your response. Could you please suggest me how better we can utilise the audio player in games like apps? Is there any exceptional cases to have this feature? May be not at very first launch. After the first interaction, Can we change/start the player music often?

Comment: Same trick applies for audio. But note that if you are really doing a game with audio, you might want to switch to the webaudio API instead (which would also require an user-interaction in mobile devices).